# Remove variable in model_parts() plot

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels, dalex

I want to remove certain variables from the plot.

```
# Packages 
library(tidymodels)
library(mlbench)

# Data 
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes")
dat <- PimaIndiansDiabetes 
dat$some_new_group[1:384] <- "group 1" 
dat$some_new_group[385:768] <- "group 2"

# Split
set.seed(123)
ind <- initial_split(dat)
dat_train <- training(ind)
dat_test <- testing(ind)

# Recipes
svm_rec <- 
  recipe(diabetes ~., data = dat_train) %>% 
  update_role(some_new_group, new_role = "group_var") %>% 
  step_rm(pressure) %>% 
  step_YeoJohnson(all_numeric_predictors())
    
# Model spec 
svm_spec <- 
  svm_rbf() %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("kernlab")

# Workflow 
svm_wf <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(svm_rec) %>% 
  add_model(svm_spec)

# Train
svm_trained <- 
  svm_wf %>% 
  fit(dat_train)

# Explainer
library(DALEXtra)

svm_exp <- explain_tidymodels(svm_trained, 
                              data = dat %>% select(-diabetes), 
                              y = dat$diabetes %>% as.numeric(), 
                              label = "SVM")
# Variable importance
set.seed(123)
svm_vp <- model_parts(svm_exp, type = "variable_importance") 
svm_vp

plot(svm_vp) +
  ggtitle("Mean-variable importance over 50 permutations", "")
```

[image]

Notice in the recipes above, I removed variable `pressure` and make a new categorical variable (`some_new_group`).

So, I can remove the variable `pressure` `some_new_group` from the plot manually like this:

```
plot(svm_vp %>% filter(variable != c("pressure", "some_new_group"))) +
  ggtitle("Mean-variable importance over 50 permutations", "")
```

[image]

But, is it possible to remove the variables when I run `explain_tidymodels()` or `model_parts()`?

Comment: Did you try manually removing variables using `select` (as you have done for the label `diabetes`)? If yes, what was the result? If no, please try it - in any case, update your question accordingly. Notice also that, according to the [documentation](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/DALEXtra/html/explain_tidymodels.html), you should use `dat_train` and not `dat` ("*data that was used for fitting*").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have variables that are not predictors or outcomes handled by your `workflow()` (like the variable you remove and your grouping variable), you want to make sure you [only pass outcomes and predictors to `explain_tidymodels()`](https://github.com/ModelOriented/DALEXtra/issues/65#issuecomment-1058516692). You'll also need to build the explainer with the parsnip model, rather than the `workflow()` which is expecting to handle those non-outcome, non-predictor variables:

```r
library(tidymodels)

# Data 
data("PimaIndiansDiabetes", package = "mlbench")
dat <- PimaIndiansDiabetes 
dat$some_new_group[1:384] <- "group 1" 
dat$some_new_group[385:768] <- "group 2"

# Split
set.seed(123)
ind <- initial_split(dat)
dat_train <- training(ind)
dat_test <- testing(ind)

# Recipes
svm_rec <- 
  recipe(diabetes ~., data = dat_train) %>% 
  update_role(some_new_group, new_role = "group_var") %>% 
  step_rm(pressure) %>% 
  step_YeoJohnson(all_numeric_predictors())

# Model spec 
svm_spec <- 
  svm_rbf() %>% 
  set_mode("classification") %>% 
  set_engine("kernlab")

# Train
svm_trained <- 
  workflow(svm_rec, svm_spec) %>% 
  fit(dat_train)

# Explainer
library(DALEXtra)
#> Loading required package: DALEX
#> Welcome to DALEX (version: 2.4.0).
#> Find examples and detailed introduction at: http://ema.drwhy.ai/
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'DALEX'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     explain

svm_exp <- explain_tidymodels(
  extract_fit_parsnip(svm_trained), 
  data = svm_rec %>% prep() %>% bake(new_data = NULL, all_predictors()), 
  y = dat_train$diabetes %>% as.numeric(), 
  label = "SVM"
)
#> Preparation of a new explainer is initiated
#>   -> model label       :  SVM 
#>   -> data              :  576  rows  7  cols 
#>   -> data              :  tibble converted into a data.frame 
#>   -> target variable   :  576  values 
#>   -> predict function  :  yhat.model_fit  will be used (  default  )
#>   -> predicted values  :  No value for predict function target column. (  default  )
#>   -> model_info        :  package parsnip , ver. 0.2.1 , task classification (  default  ) 
#>   -> predicted values  :  numerical, min =  0.08057345 , mean =  0.3540662 , max =  0.9357536  
#>   -> residual function :  difference between y and yhat (  default  )
#>   -> residuals         :  numerical, min =  0.1083522 , mean =  0.9948921 , max =  1.895405  
#>   A new explainer has been created!

# Variable importance
set.seed(123)
svm_vp <- model_parts(svm_exp, type = "variable_importance") 
svm_vp
#>       variable mean_dropout_loss label
#> 1 _full_model_         0.6861190   SVM
#> 2      glucose         0.5919956   SVM
#> 3         mass         0.6673947   SVM
#> 4     pregnant         0.6700007   SVM
#> 5          age         0.6701185   SVM
#> 6     pedigree         0.6702812   SVM
#> 7      triceps         0.6760106   SVM
#> 8      insulin         0.6777355   SVM
#> 9   _baseline_         0.5020752   SVM

plot(svm_vp) +
  ggtitle("Mean-variable importance over 50 permutations", "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you have these "extra" variables in your workflow that shouldn't be used for explainability, then you'll need to do some extra work and can't rely on the `workflow()` alone.